# Regarding an extraction statement in perl

Tags: perl

```
(my $batch_name = $batch_dir) =~ s#.*/##;
```

I had come across this statement while going through a script and tried to understand it. Even googling the RHS did not return anything useful.  Can someone please help me understand what this statement means???

which out of the two scalars are affected??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it deletes the longest prefix ending with a `/` from a copy of the `$batch_dir` variable, eg. producing a leafname from a file system path or extracting the script, query and fragment part of a properly escaped url.

the idiom actually comprises 2 operations:

```
 my $batch_name = $batch_dir;
 batch_name =~ s#.*/##;
```

without the parentheses the substitution would be applied to `$batch_dir` and `$batch_name` would be set to the value returned from the substitution operator, the success status (at least 1 substitution has occurred => `1`, `undef` else).

Answer (score 0):

Parens `()` has higher priority than `=~`, so the instruction inside parens is executed before.

First the assignement `my $batch_name = $batch_dir;` is done, then the substitution `$batch_name =~ s#.*/##;`

Only the `$batch_name` variable is affected by the substitution.